# Sequelize converts UTC time to wrong local zone

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a table that stores datetime with time zone in UTC zone. It is stored in PostgreSQL. The data is in the table is not converted to any zone which is desirable. However, when I query using `findAll` method, it returns the result as time zone +5 than -5 (which is the correct server zone). I kept the default `useUTC` to `true` without setting `true` or `false` as `true` is the default. Below is an example:

Database record `"2020-10-09T03:49:28.652Z"`

Sequelize response `"2020-10-09T08:49:28.652Z"`

Expected response `"2020-10-09T22:49:28.652Z"`

I am using this workaround for the time being.
Note: that this is run in ExtJS 6.2 [Chart axes renderer function](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.chart.axis.Axis.html#cfg-renderer).

```
renderer: function (axis, date_str, layoutContext, lastLabelText) {
   var d = new Date(date_str.replace('Z', '').replace('T', ' ') + ' UTC');
   d.setHours(d.getHours() - 5);
   return Ext.Date.format(new Date(d), 'H:i:s');
```

My worry is that Sequlize uses user timezone than server timezone. Also, this timezone might not be correct during daylight saving.

Is there any good fix for sequelize and the render function above?

Edit:

I have added the `findAll` raw SQL query from the log:

```
SELECT "id", "capture_datetime", "pco2", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "bos_pco2" AS "bos_pco2" WHERE "bos_pco2"."capture_datetime" IS NOT NULL ORDER BY "bos_pco2"."capture_datetime" DESC LIMIT 30;
```

Capture date_time is a column a Date column with UTC date and time.
The other raw SELECT query works now when UTC datetime is supplied.

This Raw select query is not working too. In PG Admin, I get a result but no result with sequelize.

```
SELECT * FROM bos_chl_a_pc_pe WHERE capture_datetime 
        BETWEEN '2020-10-10T22:41:44.000Z'::TIMESTAMP and '2020-10-11T00:41:44.045Z'::TIMESTAMP 
        ORDER BY capture_datetime;
```

Answer (score 1):

By default Sequelize will use the timezone of the system that it is running on and convert dates returned to that timezone format. If you want to force Sequelize to use UTC dates (and not observe DST) then you will need to specify the timezone option when you create the Sequelize connection.

```js
const instance = new Sequelize(
  databaseName,
  userName,
  userPassword,
  {
    host: databaseHost,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    // specify to use UTC and the timezone here
    dialectOptions: {
      useUTC: true, // tell the driver you want to use UTC
      timezone: 'Etc/GMT0', // this works for me with mariadb
    },
    timezone: 'Etc/GMT0', // the github issue indicates the TZ here for postgres
  }
);
```

See this Github issue for more info: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/854

Comment: Unfortunately the code is not working when I used it as it is. Do I need to change the second timezone value as `Etc/GMT-5`?

Comment: @wondim you are setting the timezone for the client so it will depend on how you want the results to be formatted.

Comment: It is possible to convert the UTC to local as far as I get unmodified UTC with different libraries. The problem is, it is not clear what sequelize is expecting and returning. For instance, when I query a data between two times, PgAdmin returns several records, but sequelize returns 0. This means, it is still converting the timestamp in between the ranges. That is my problem. I don't want sequelize to change date to any format.

Comment: @wondim you might need to include your queries as well - are you sure the conditions are being created correctly?

Comment: I have added a query that is still not working in my question under `Edit`. The select between dates works now.